# Alfresco community - wiki page access without any authentication

Tags: alfresco

Is it possible to visit alfresco wiki pages without a user name and password?
I don't want my all users to have an account to read my wiki pages.

I have created some consumer users and they must have to log in and read the wiki. I don't want to be like this.

Is there any way creating wiki pages any Guest user can read without authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link that is use full for understanding how we can create a page in alfresco share.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/tutorial-share-add-page.html

For solving your issue, find what is the location for the wiki page and update the below thing in XML.

```
<authentication>user</authentication>
```

To create a page that can only be accessed by administrators using an authentication level of admin. To create a page that can be accessed by any user, including those who are not logged in, set the authentication level to none.